# Cypher: Find value count inside node property arrays

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm tring to find all values and their occurrence count inside relationships' property arrays.

I have three nodes and each of them has a relationship property which is a string array.

1- ["444"], 2- ["222", "111"] and 3- ["444"]

What I tried is:

```
MATCH (:Person { field: "B" })-[r:ALIKE]->(person)
RETURN r.at, COUNT(r.at)
```

Current result:

```
r.at            COUNT(r.at)
["222", "111"]  1
["444"]         2
```

What I expect:

```
r.at            COUNT(r.at)
["222"]         1
["444"]         2
["111"]         1
```

or

```
r.at            COUNT(r.at)
"222"           1
"444"           2
"111"           1
```

would be better if I get the values instead arrays.

And if one more relationship has "111" and "222" as well, it should be like this:

```
r.at            COUNT(r.at)
"222"           2
"444"           2
"111"           2
```

How should I change my current query?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's recreate the test data set:

```
CREATE
  (:Person {id: 1, at: ['444']}),
  (:Person {id: 2, at: ['222', '111']}),
  (:Person {id: 3, at: ['444']})
```

To count individual strings, [`UNWIND`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/unwind/) each list and count the number of Person nodes (`p`) for their elements:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
UNWIND p.at AS at
RETURN at, count(p)
```

The result is:

```
╒═════╤══════════╕
│"at" │"count(p)"│
╞═════╪══════════╡
│"111"│1         │
├─────┼──────────┤
│"444"│2         │
├─────┼──────────┤
│"222"│1         │
└─────┴──────────┘
```

Comment: In my case r was the relationship but I got the idea. Thanks a lot.